# What is the Math.NET equivalent of numpy.where?

Tags: python, numpy, ironpython, mathnet-numerics, rhinoceros

I'm porting a piece of python code that currently uses numpy, to IronPython (the reasons for this have to do with the specifics of the platform I'm scripting in).

Due to incompatibilities of numpy and IronPython, I need to replace every numpy function with its Math.NET equivalent, which I have added as an external reference.

Being a total newbie in Math.NET, I have trouble finding the equivalent of the `numpy.where()` function.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does math.NET even have an equivalent of ndarray?